# SQL Server Dynamic SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a text file with about 400,000 records which have to be read, processed and inserted into a table. I'm using a stored procedure to do the same. The records are pipe separated as shown below

```
a | b | c .... 180 columns (1st record)
d | e | f .... 180 columns (2nd record)
.
.
.
x | y | z .....180 columns (4,00,00th record)
```

In the stored procedure, one insert statement was being fired for each record. I created a dynamic SQL query that would club 1,000 records in one insert but noticed that the execution time did not decrease. In fact, the SQL dynamic query created for a single record (includes isnull and cast functions for each column) takes more time than than the time taken to insert a single record into the table.

Is there a way I reduce the time taken to perform the task at hand?

EDIT
The dynamic SQL query looks something like this (just a tiny snapshot)

```
CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR(20)) + ''',' + 
CAST(@N_ER AS VARCHAR(20)) + ',' + 
CAST(@N_INSDE AS VARCHAR(20)) + ',' + 
CAST(@N_CODE AS VARCHAR(20)) + ',' + 
CAST(@NJOB_NUMBER AS VARCHAR(30)) + ',' + 
CAST(@NNUMBER AS VARCHAR(30)) + ',''' + 
ISNULL(DESTINATION,'') + ''',''' +  
ISNULL(@VPE_ID,'') + ''',''' + 
ISNULL(dbo.fn_NEW_CARD(@VAN),'') +
```

Or is there a way to improve the concatenation using some other set of functions maybe?

Comment: How often do you commit?

Comment: I'm not sure it can handle so many columns but have you tried the import wizard or SSIS? You could bulk insert into a stage table then use SQL to clean data.

Comment: @jarlh I haven't explicitly used the commit statement in my code. When the insert happens I guess it is committed.

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci Once I bulk insert into a stage table, I'll have to take them in a cursor, do the processing and again insert them into the table. Or maybe fire an update query once the processing for a row is complete. But will it reduce execution time substantially?

Comment: I meant insert the data into the stage with the columns already separated. You can tell the wizard that the column delimiter is |, so you will just need to clean the column values and not identify each column.

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci Once the columns are separated I also have to do some processing on each column. So once they're inserted in the table with the pipes removed I'l have to pick them up again to complete the processing and finally insert/update the table.

Comment: If you have the columns already split inside a table, then manipulating each value separately would greatly increase your process time. You could even do different updates to clean the values, one column at a time.

Comment: Did you consider using SSIS instead? I faced a similar task not too long ago and ended up with creating a SSIS package which took care of the inserts...

Comment: @Tyron78 No, I haven't actually. Which part of my problem statement would the SSIS fix?

Comment: @Amit using SSIS you can perform almost all required tasks: Reading the file, splitting up the strings, performing the bulk insert... One approach would be to define a SSIS package with a source in it (Flatfile, C# or whatever) which takes care of reading the file and splitting the string and a destination which performs the insert.

Comment: @Tyron78 Thank you so much for the information. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using EXEC to run your Dynamic SQL - have you tried ExecuteSQL (with parameters) The advantage is that SQL can cache the query plan - which is a fairly significant saving on 400K inserts.

To be honest - SSIS is by far the best way to do it - Right click on the DB, select Tasks and Import Data then follow the wizard - you can even save the created package for later use in a Job.

Comment: Yes, importing might do - or use VS to build a new package (OK, OK - not that easy on first try - but it IS manageable.) ;-)

Comment: just spotted dbo.fn_NEW_CARD() in the code - Functions like this are always a red-flag - I'd look at what this func is doing and try and inline it into your SQL - possibly into a temp table first...

Comment: @johnMcTighe Thank you very much for the useful suggestions.